# Cannot get current device settings: Operation not supported ethtool CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, ethtool

Received an error  `"Cannot get current device settings: Operation not supported ethtool"` while changing network speed using ethtool command on centos,

```
 # ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full

  Cannot get current device settings: Operation not supported ethtool
  not setting speed
  not setting duplex
  not setting autoneg
```

Comment: You can't do this in a virtual machine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton why ?